# Photo picker with alternate intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

I want to create picker which provide choice image from gallery or take photo from camera. This picker will be used for application with `minSdkVersion 16`.

I can take required view, if I use `EXTRA_ALTERNATE_INTENTS` intent:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK),
       photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent choicer = Intent.createChooser(photoIntent, "Получить изображение");
choicer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALTERNATE_INTENTS, new Intent[]{galleryIntent});
```

All icons are placed in a **single row**

[image]

But this solution not working on API < 23.

I tried to use `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`(available from API 5):

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK),
       photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent choicer = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Получить изображение");
choicer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{photoIntent});
```

The picker starts to work from API > 15, but icons was placed at **two rows**

[image]

**How to create picker which can work with multiple intents and icons will be placed in a single row?**

Comment: You build your own chooser UI, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. The styling of the device's chooser is up to Google and the device manufacturer/custom ROM developer.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you share link to example?